# How can MapKit be loaded on an inactive block using SvelteKit?

Tags: mapkit, sveltekit

I am building a modal component that displays a map using MapKit when activated by the user.

I noticed that I am unable to load MapKit when the component is inside a block that is not active yet. Specifically, I get the error: `[MapKit] 'parent' must either be a DOM element or its ID.`

Here is the Svelte file:

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { display } from '$lib/store.js'; // Currently set to false

    onMount(() => {
        mapkit.init({
            authorizationCallback: function (done) {
                fetch('/api/gettoken')
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then(done);
            }
        });
        let map = new mapkit.Map('map');
    }
</script> 

{#if $display}
    <div class="parent" on:click|self={disable}>
        <div class="child" in:fly={{ y: 200, duration: 100 }}>
            <div id="map" />
        </div>
    </div>
{/if}
```

I was thinking of calling `mapkit.init` when `display` is changed to true, but that doesn't seem to work for me. Is there any flexibility to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe create the map as soon as the container element exists

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { display } from '$lib/store.js'; // Currently set to false

    onMount(() => {
        mapkit.init({
            authorizationCallback: function (done) {
                fetch('/api/gettoken')
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then(done);
            }
        });
    }

    let mapContainer
    let map
    $: if(mapContainer) map = new mapkit.Map('map-container');

</script> 

{#if $display}
    <div class="parent" on:click|self={disable}>
        <div class="child" in:fly={{ y: 200, duration: 100 }}>
            <div id="map-container" bind:this={mapContainer}/>
        </div>
    </div>
{/if}
```

Comment: Creating the binding worked flawlessly. Thank you!

Comment: I noticed that this only works when I load the page directly. For example, if your code was on a `/map` and I accessed it from `home` first, the map would not load. Does any solution come to mind?

Comment: @RBarnes Hm no, sorry, I don't see what that does change to make it behave differently... hope you've already found out